# loosing custom feature while move content database to different environment?

Tags: 2007, custom

loosing custom feature while move content database to different environments. Here is the thing.

1. Created New web application in new environment.
2. deployed WSP from old to new environment.
3. copied content database from old to new environment.
4. attached with content db to new environment web application using STSADM.
5. Finally missing already activated features those already activated in old content database
   and not showing in enviroment.

   Old environment was SP1 and new environment is SP2. That is only change. I an not understanding why we are missing already activate features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some caveats associated with the difference in installation of two different environments. It is suggested to run the same service pack level on both source and destination SharePoint if possible. Therefore, as a first step, I would suggest you installing the SP2 on other environment (environment with SP1) and try moving the content DB again.

Make sure you install all webparts, solutions, features, etc on new server before you restore the content database, so that it can find all the features it's looking for.

Make sure you copy any files that may be living in the file system that you need, sometimes people have css/javascript here.  (This refers to files in the hive)

Comment: I have an issue for installing SP1. The new environment is Windows 2008 R2 version. I have to go with SP2 installation.

Comment: What I meant is try installing SP2 on environment with SP1, then move the Content DB again. Ready my above reply again. Also, it would be great if you could list down the details of both the enviroments.

Answer (score 1):

I was not attaching content DB with "System Account". I was attached with farm admin account. I think farm admin account doesn't have full permissions execute modify existing features. Anyway it is good to know for me.